# RabbitMQ bind queue to exchange through API failing with 404 error

Tags: api, rabbitmq

I am trying to bind a queue within a vhost to an exchange using the RabbitMQ API and I'm getting a 404 error.

The command result from fiddler is:

```
POST http://localhost:15672/api/bindings/dev.jhilden_client/AuthComplete.EPCIS/AuthComplete HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.3; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/4.0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:15672
Content-Length: 33

{"routing_key":"","arguments":[]}
```

The vhost, queue, and exchange all already exist.

I've created a powershell script that runs all of the rabbitMQ setup, the last step of which is to create this binding and that binding is failing.  You can easily run the script and get the error.  Any help would be much appreciated.

https://github.com/jayhilden/RabbitMQSetup/blob/master/rabbitMQSetup.ps1

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I was going off of documentation from an older version of the API.  The correct POST command is: /api/bindings/{vhost}/e/{exchange}/q/{queue}

Here is the correct API documentation:

http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_2_3/priv/www/api/index.html

I've put up my full powershell script for creating a vhost, creating exchange, creating queues, and binding queues here:

https://github.com/jayhilden/RabbitMQSetup/blob/master/rabbitMQSetup.ps1

Hopefully someone else will find it useful.

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you very much.